# Dataframe: Con función lambda, no puedo procesar valor de columna en función de otra

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

Tengo un **DataFrame** llamado **FuelPrice**, el cual tiene dos columnas.

```
FuelPrice = pd.DataFrame({'name':'fuel_ATA_22','fuel_ATA_23','fuel_COL_12','fuel_COL_11'], 
                           'value':['0.78','0.77','0.79','0.73']})
```

Intento sumar el valor **regasDm3** a los valores de la columna **value** siempre y cuando el string **fuel_ATA** este dentro de la columna **name**. Estoy utilizando el siguiente código, pero no funcionan.

```
regasDm3=73.5

FuelPrice['value'] = FuelPrice[['name','value']].apply(lambda x,y: x.str.contains("fuel_ATA", y+regasDm3))
```

Les agradecería sus consejos.

Answer (score 1):

> Intento sumar el valor regasDm3 a los valores de la columna value siempre y cuando el string fuel_ATA este dentro de la columna name.

### `zip()` con ambas columnas

La función [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) retorna un iterable con tuplas.

> Returns an iterator of tuples

Se puede validar cada elemento de la columna `"name"` a la vez que se modifica condicionalmente cada elemento de la columna `"value"`:

```
a = []

for name,value in zip(FuelPrice["name"],FuelPrice["value"]):
    if "fuel_ATA" in str(name):
        a.append(float(value) + regasDm3)
    else:
        a.append(float(value))
        continue
```

Aquí se están usando dos variables temporales `name` y `value`, cada una toma el valor de cada elemento de sus columnas respectivas. Por lo tanto, se adicionan a la lista elementos dependiendo se se cumple la condición.

### `map()` para simplificar

La función [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) itera sobre cada elemento de un iterable, aplicando una instrucción a dicho elemento.

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable

Se puede hacer lo mismo con un ciclo `for`, con `map()` en una sola linea.

```
b = list(map(lambda a: float(a[1]) + regasDm3 if "fuel_ATA" in str(a[0]) else float(a[1]),zip(FuelPrice["name"],FuelPrice["value"])))
```

Esto lo hace relativamente más difícil de leer, pero ahorra lineas de código.

*¿Por qué solo se usa un argumento en la función `lambda`?*

En el caso del ciclo `for`, es un caso especial, se pueden usar dos variables temporales. Con `map()` ocurre distinto, se necesita acceder a cada elemento de la tupla por su indice. **No sería válido pasar dos argumentos por la `lambda`.**

### `df.itertuples()` en una compresión de listas

Al tener la necesidad de evaluar elementos de distintas columnas es muy apto hacer uso del método [`itertuples()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html).

> Iterate over DataFrame rows as namedtuples.

Este retorna múltiples objetos de Pandas, llamados namedtuples. Estos contienen todos los valores de una fila. Al usar el parámetro `index = False` se reduce la longitud de elementos en este objeto debido a que se elimina el indice de la fila. A pesar de no ser objetos nativos del lenguaje, son casteables a listas.

```
c = [regasDm3 + float(x[1]) if "fuel_ATA" in x[0] else float(x[1]) for x in list(FuelPrice.itertuples(index = False))]
```

En esta ´compresión, se hace las validaciones de los elementos de la columna "name", dependiendo del resultado de la validación se añade el respectivo elemento de la columna `"value"`, sumado o no sumado con `regasDm3`.

### ¿Por qué no se usa `apply()`?

> Estoy utilizando el siguiente código, pero no funcionan.

```
...
```

Es muy complicado tomar en cuanta valores de distintas columnas usando el método `apply()`con una `lambda` como parámetro. Esto por que hay que validar elemento de otra columna y realizar operaciones (suma)
en otra columna. De cualquier otra forma se puede escribir una función más elaborador y usar en `apply()`.

Cualquiera de los tres maneras genera una lista, asignables a una columna del `DataFrame`.

```
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

muestra

```
[74.28, 74.27, 0.79, 0.73]
[74.28, 74.27, 0.79, 0.73]
[74.28, 74.27, 0.79, 0.73]
```

Por lo tanto,

```
FuelPrice["value"] = a or b or c
print(FuelPrice)
```

muestra

```
          name  value
0  fuel_ATA_22  74.28
1  fuel_ATA_23  74.27
2  fuel_COL_12   0.79
3  fuel_COL_11   0.73
```

Espero te haya servido de algo.

Answer (score 1):

Mi alternativa:

```
for index in range(len(FuelPrice)):
    if FuelPrice.loc[index, 'name'].startswith("fuel_ATA"):
        FuelPrice.loc[index, 'value'] += regasDm3
```

Es el viejo y conocido recorrido explicito por la matriz, actualizando in-situ cada valor.

Nuevamente, el beneficio es flexibilidad. Mañana necesitaras aplicar un factor distinto según cada tipo de combustible, con esta alternativa sera pan comido.

**Comprobación**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

FuelPrice = pd.DataFrame({'name':['fuel_ATA_22','fuel_ATA_23','fuel_COL_12','fuel_COL_11'],'value':[0.78,0.77,0.79,0.73]})
regasDm3=73.5
print(FuelPrice)
for index in range(len(FuelPrice)):
    if FuelPrice.loc[index, 'name'].startswith("fuel_ATA"):
        FuelPrice.loc[index, 'value'] += regasDm3

print(FuelPrice)
```

prooduce

```
          name  value
0  fuel_ATA_22   0.78
1  fuel_ATA_23   0.77
2  fuel_COL_12   0.79
3  fuel_COL_11   0.73
          name  value
0  fuel_ATA_22  74.28
1  fuel_ATA_23  74.27
2  fuel_COL_12   0.79
3  fuel_COL_11   0.73
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estás usando `pandas` se lo puede aprovechar al máximo:

```
FuelPrice.loc[FuelPrice['name'].str.startswith('fuel_ATA'), 'value'] += regasDm3
```

Detalle:

- Con `FuelPrice['name'].str.startswith('fuel_ATA')` generamos una serie de valores booleanos que representan las filas dónde en `name` encontramos  `fuel_ATA`
- Luego simplemente seleccionando etas filas actualizamos el valor de `value`